# Accessing current_settings function within a plperl function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, perl, plperl

I am writing my first plperl function in Postgres and I have a need to access some values in the current_settings() area (by use of that call) -- and I am wondering what the best solution to doing so is?

In plpgsql I can do something like:

```
DECLARE
  cid int;
BEGIN
  select nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.customerId', true), '') :: int into cid;
END ...
```

Just wondering about the equivalent of accessing system functions like current_setting within a Perl plperl script..

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of the [database access functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plperl-builtins.html#PLPERL-DATABASE), e.g.:

```
$rv = spi_exec_query("select nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.customerId', true), '')::int as cid");
$cid = $rv->{rows}[0]->{cid};
```

Comment: Well -- ugh -- I feel like a sort of doh moment!  That makes total sense.. for some reason I was thinking internal functions would be "different".  Overthinking perhaps!  Thanks!

Comment: I am getting a syntax error near/at the $q$ part .. is that ..ah.. legal for within a plperl function??  The error is:  ERROR: syntax error at line 9, near "$q$.. The code is:   # Ok -- get our customerId from the current_settings..
  $rv = spi_exec_query($q$
    select nullif(current_setting('jwt.claims.customerId', true), '')::int as cid
    $q$);

Comment: I've tried to use postgres quotes in a pearl function... Sorry, the answer updated.

Comment: Thanks -- I thought as much -- too bad, those $Q$ type quote things are handy!  :)